# How to post some data and get results using MEAN stack and ngResource

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack, angularjs-resource

I am working on a application and I am using MEAN stack as technology. In AngularJS, I am using ngResource to CRUD operations. Can any one suggest how to send username and password to server and get response back to check if the credentials are valid. I need help in ngResource and mongoose code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the mean.js boilerplate:
https://github.com/meanjs/mean

You'll see how they do it pretty quickly:

`moduleName.client.controller.js` will make an http call, using the injected http. Here is an example of the call being made from `/modules/users/client/controllers/authentication.client.controller.js` (with some edits to the code to make it easier to see what you're looking for):

```
AuthenticationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 'Authentication'];

function AuthenticationController($scope, $state, $http, Authentication, ) {
  ...
  vm.authentication = Authentication;

  $http.post('/api/auth/signup', vm.credentials).success(function (response) {
    // If successful we assign the response to the global user model
    vm.authentication.user = response;

  }).error(function (response) {
    vm.error = response.message;
  });
}
```

Now, this call is posted to '/api/auth/signup'. The file that handles this route is located in `/modules/users/server/routes/auth.server.routes.js`:

```
modules.exports = function(app) {
  var users = require('../controllers/users.server.controller');
  ...
  app.route('/api/auth/signup').post(users.signup);
}
```

As you can see, the route (the url) matches the one you called from the client controller. As that $http call from the controller was a `$http.post()`, the route entry must match. You can see that it does above.
The parameter `users.signup` passed above refers to a function in yet another file: `/modules/users/server/controllers/users/users.authentication.server.controller.js`. This is your main controller for the authentication part of the `users` module. Now, within this file we can see the `signup` function is exported:

```
/* note: there are global variables here, see below */
exports.signup = function (req, res) {
  // For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
  delete req.body.roles;

  // Init user and add missing fields
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.provider = 'local';
  user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

  // Then save the user
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      // Remove sensitive data before login
      user.password = undefined;
      user.salt = undefined;

      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(user);
        }
      });
   }
 });
};
```

Now, a lot is going on here, but we can break it down.

The `req` variable is the post request as passed by $http. The `res` variable is the response the client expects to receive back.
Notice how `vm.credentials` was passed in `$http.post('/api/auth/signup/', vm.credentials)`? This is bound to `req.body` and may be accessed by your server controller from that.

So in this example, the req.body is the required data to create a new user on the server. This is done using mongoose, which has a schema called User. Access this by declaring globals at the top of your controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = mongoose.model('User');
```

You can see that a new user is instantiated above. It is saved via the mongoose call `.save()`.

Lastly, your server functions should response to the client's request using the `res` variable passed to the function. See how once the user is created successfully, the function calls

```
res.jsonp(user);
```

This is `success()` to the client, which accepts the response and binds it to a local variable `vm.authentication.user`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mtro. Though it does not solve problem entirely but it helps a lot.